# Map 2D tiles onto 3D sphere Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I want to make Map of the Earth using OpenStreetMap [tiles](https://www.maptiler.com/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/#3/45.04/55.86).

When zoom is 0 I should see Earth as a sphere. When zooming in, new tiles should be downloaded and pasted to required positions on the sphere.

I know how to get tiles and its positions on the sphere, but how I can actually implement replacing old tiles with new ones in Unity?

The result should be like [this](https://i.imgur.com/cMKkRZ3.mp4)